# How to Link Local Python Help Documents Using Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

How can I get my Sphinx RST file to include a link to the "contents.html" Python help page?

**More Details**

I have an RST help document (*index.rst*) in an offline environment.  I have downloaded and successfully built the Python documentation using the command `make.bat html`.  I then copied this documentation to C:\Temp\PyDoc.

I then updated my conf.py file to include the following Intersphinx mapping:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('C:/Temp/PyDoc', None)}
```

Then, within my *index.rst* file, I have something like:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   :ref:`Python <python:contents>`
```

The *Python* link is removed from the resulting documentation with the warning message:

> WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document ':ref:`Python <python:contents>`'

I have verified that the output contains the text:

> loading intersphinx inventory from C:/Temp/PyDoc/objects.inv...

I have also verified that the "contents" tag exists within the Python documentation by running:

```
python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx "C:/Temp/PyDoc/objects.inv" | findstr contents
```

Which generates output that includes the line:

> contents      Python Documentation contents      : contents.html

Does anyone know how to reference this external documentation from my RST file?

Comment: Does it work if you use `:any:` instead of `:ref:`?

Comment: Sadly, no.  I get the same warning, but with `:ref:` replaced by `:any:`.

Comment: In any case, I would not expect `:ref:` to work, since that role is used for cross-references to explicit labels such as `.. _contents:`. The page that you want to link to does not contain any label (see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Doc/contents.rst).

Comment: I have not tried to create documentation locally. ``:any:`Python <python:contents>` `` works for me if it is a regular inline cross-reference (not a toctree item), using `intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3', None)}`.

Answer (score 2):

In the configuration for intersphinx, the [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict)'s key's value is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), which consists of comma-separated values, not colon-separated.

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('C:/Temp/PyDoc', None)}
```

**EDIT**

[`toctree`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) entries need a valid target, which can be a file relative to the current file or absolute as starting from the documentation root where your `conf.py` resides.  Also the target may be an URL.  I suspect that the HTML you made is none of the above, so you need to move it to a place where Sphinx can find it.

The syntax should be for documentation, not a Python object, because the page is a table of contents.  I did not try this example because I don't have the Python docs downloaded and built, so I doubt it will work.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    :doc:`Python <python:contents>`
```

Or you can just use the URL (or similar relative or absolute target).  This works for me with a fully qualified URL.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    Python <https://docs.python.org/3/contents.html>
```

Finally you could try an include, but I think that is not what you really want.

Comment: This fixes the error I was seeing when trying to use the new syntax for `intersphinx_mapping`, but still doesn't result in a link to the appropriate document.  I have upvoted this answer, since it helped me.  I also updated the question to reflect the new behavior after applying this fix, since I am still unable to generate a link to the referenced document.

Comment: Here is the bug report for toctree not supporting intersphinx: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1836